# how do I find a way to use ssh and rsync

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, subprocess, rsync

I have troubles using to implement ssh and rsync including a private key in python, including Popen (subprocess).

Basically the rsync syntax to use should be:

```
$ rsync -az -e --log-file=$logdir/logfile.out \
'ssh -e /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa' user@server:/target-directory
```

What I have is this:

```
import subprocess
```

First, I build my logdir path - with variables :

```
logdir = [basedir + '/' + 'log' + '/' + today + '/' + 'pfdcopy_' \
+ typ + '_' + ts + '.log.txt']
```

Then I build the target directory:

```
target= ['jboss' + '@' + targetsvr + ':' + /data']
```

Finally, I try to run this code

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '-az', '--log-file=%s' % \
logdir/logfile.out , '-e', 'ssh', '-i', \
'/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa', target])
```

It's quite complex, I know, mainly because of the variables, and the quotation marks.

Running this, I get always different syntax errors with p1.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

edited (08-10-2018):

here is my complete runnable code snippet -

```
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
import os
import fnmatch

now = datetime.now()
today = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
ts = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
sign_output_dir = '/Users/fanta4/Documents/python-files/outgoing'
mandator = 'BTV'
formsize = 'A4'
basedir = '/Users/fanta4/Documents'
pdf_to_send = []
targetsvr = 'nas1'

doktyp = (
'WPGEBUEHR', 'WPDURCHFU', 'WPABR', 'WPABRKF', 'WPABRVK', 'WPABRTILG', 'WPABRERTR', 'WPAMIS', 'WPSTREP',
'WPABLAUF', 'WPAVISO', 'WPAUSZUG', 'WPERTRAEG', 'WPSIKTEST', 'WPTRANS', 'WPANSCHAFF', 'KKKONTOMIT', 'KRKURSUEW',
'WPVERLUSTA', 'WPVERLUSTG')


os.chdir(sign_output_dir)
for file in os.listdir(sign_output_dir):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.pdf'):
        pdf_to_send.append(file)

os.chdir(sign_output_dir)
print('debug: doktyp ist: {}'.format(formsize))
for typ in doktyp:
    if typ in str(pdf_to_send):
        ts = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%Hh-%Mm-%Ss")
        print('typ: {:12s} exists -> will be transfered to nas1'.format(typ))
        logdir = [basedir + '/' + 'log' + '/' + mandator + '/' + today + '/' + 'pfdcopy_' + typ + '_' + ts + '.log.txt']
        target = ['jboss' + '@' + targetsvr + '/data' + '/' + mandator + typ]
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(
            ['rsync', '-az', '--log-file=%s' % logdir, '-e', 'ssh', '-i', '/Users/fanta4/.ssh/id_rsa', typ, '-l', target])
        p1.returncode
        if p1 > 0:
            print('debug: Error with rsync of typ: {} to target: {}'.format(typ, targetsvr))
        else:
            print('debug: rsync mandator: {:3s} with typ: {:12s} succeeded'.format(mandator, typ))
    else:
        print('debug: typ: {:12s} does not exist'.format(typ))

logfile = ['/data' + '/' + 'log' + '/' + mandator + '/' + ts]
print('debug: pls see logfile in: {}'.format(logfile))
```

If I run this code, I get:

```
/Users/fanta4/anaconda3/bin/python "/Users/fanta4/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/entw/python/prog/rsync-test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
/Users/fanta4/Documents/python-files/outgoing
debug: doktyp ist: A4
File "/Users/fanta4/Library/Mobile
Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/entw/python/prog/rsync-test.py", line 37, in <module>
typ: WPGEBUEHR    exists -> will be transfered to nas1
['rsync', '-az', '--log-file=%s' % logdir, '-e', 'ssh', '-i',   '/Users/fanta4/.ssh/id_rsa', typ, '-l', target])
  File "/Users/fanta4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709,   in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/Users/fanta4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1275, in _execute_child
restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Why are you making `logdir` and `target` be lists, rather than strings? An argument vector is *one* list, where all entries in that list must be strings; if you start nesting other lists inside the outer one, what you have is no longer a structure that can be passed directly to the operating system's `execv` family of syscalls.

Comment: ...that said, the bigger issue here is that you aren't actually including your precise error, *or* code that generates that error. See [mcve] guidelines in the Help Center -- if we don't have the actual error, we're just guessing; and if we don't have code that generates the error, we can't test our (or anyone else's) answers.

Comment: thanks for your input. I neglected the code, because I thought to write code like mine is generally not the best way, and someone might say - pls use module xy instead before using this complicated way of solving a rsync problem... But anyway, no problem to show my code, folks.

Comment: [mcve] guidelines call for the **shortest** *runnable* code. Which is to say, verifiability is important, but so is isolating the issue; see "Tricks for Trimming" at http://sscce.org/ for hints on how to meet both criteria.

Comment: ...that said, looking at the code -- `target` is a list. The list passed as an argv needs to have strings, not other lists, as its members.

Comment: ok thanks! I'll modify this asap and give you my feedback

Comment: after modifying logdir and target to type string - not list - rsync is working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is exemplified by the following lines (when used to generate items which are later used as elements inside an argument vector):

```
logdir = [basedir + '/' + 'log' + '/' + mandator + '/' + today + '/' + 'pfdcopy_' + typ + '_' + ts + '.log.txt']
target = ['jboss' + '@' + targetsvr + '/data' + '/' + mandator + typ]
```

You're defining `logdir` and `target` as *lists* (with only one string inside them), whereas they need to be *strings*.

Just take out the square brackets that create a list, and you'll have strings instead:

```
logdir = basedir + '/log/' + mandator + '/' + today + '/pfdcopy_' + typ + '_' + ts + '.log.txt'
target = 'jboss@' + targetsvr + '/data/' + mandator + typ
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what syntax errors you are getting. It would really for the benefit of everyone for you to include that information. I am guessing it's missing the  missing quotes around one the string parameters.

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen([
    'rsync', '-az', '--log-file=%s' % 'logdir/logfile.out',
    '-e', 'ssh', '-i',
    '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa', target
])
```